# About elastcisearch memory Xms and Xmx fort Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

Can anyone recomend the values for Xmx and Xms, as I have found diferent information in internet about the recomended giga rams. Most time I find that it should be 32gb, So i have this in my jvm.options.d

-Xms32g
-Xmx32g

I'm using elasticsearch 7.16.3. My server has 378gb and its a 64 bit. I usually use 20% to 30% of my server gigarams.

Thanks